# How do I delete a backup on the time machine as well as an account

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, mac-pro

I have the following issue for which I cannot find the answers.

Problem 1: I have on my time machine a backup from a computer that I do not own anymore. I cannot delete this. Not a big thing, just eating a bit of space but how to delete?

Problem 2 (the real one): after I had to restore macOS, my mac does not want to backup anymore through time machine. It starts and then somehow stops with a message that it cannot make a backup. I tried everything out there and cannot get the routine to normally start again. So I have decided to start all over again. This however does not work since the Mac keeps recognising the backup. I tried to delete (same as above, not working). I tried to rename (not working). I tried to rename the computer and then start one (link with backup is restored in the meantime so not working).

So also on this one the question, how does one get rid of a backup on the time machine and start all over again?

Comment: Are you backing up to a TimeCapsule, an external HDD/SSD, or a NAS, how much free space is available on the (backup) disk?

Comment: On the Time Capsule.